# Does Spring Boot automatically resolve message keys in javax and hibernate validation annotations

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, bean-validation

I was writing a Spring Boot Application. I wanted to know does Spring Boot automatically resolve message keys in javax and hibernate validation annotations. For example:

```
@NotEmpty(message = "${message.key}")
String name;
```

I have provided `@PropertySource` in my application with message properties file and file is also in my classpath. The keys are resolving with `@Value` but they are not being resolved in validation annotations.

What could be the reason for this?

Do I need configure a message source bean? Because I have seen examples working without configuring the message source bean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are your messages in the correct place? Spring Boot [automatically registers a `MessageSource` bean for you](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/MessageSourceAutoConfiguration.java), so you should put your messages in the `src/main/resources/messages.properties` file. If you have enabled the auto-configuration and also have hibernate-validator dependency on the classpath, everything should work out of the box.

Also `@PropertySource` is related to application's configuration properties and not messages so the fact that it's not resolving them is to be expected ^^

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So the name of the property file name has to be message.properties? What if i want to have a different name for the file or multiple validation messages file?

Comment: Should i use spring.messages.basename property if i have a different name file or multiple files. Is there a property file name syntax for it to automatically pickup multiple files?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly how you'd override the default file name. You can also name multiple files, the property accepts a comma-separated list

Comment: Take a look at [this link](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html) (under internationalization) to see what you configure/override.

Comment: Thanks for the help.

Comment: Note that the messages to resolve must be of the form "{message.key}", not "${message.key}".